# Clone Date Range Picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, clone, daterangepicker

After lot of research I was unable to find the question related to me and the plugin I used.

I am trying to clone [DateRangePicker](http://www.daterangepicker.com/#example4) but failing to do so.
I am changing the `id` of clone div and then initializing the datepickerrange with the newly set `id`.

Below is what I tried in which I am only able to change date of clone field once and then it doesn't respond again when tried to change the date.

Please let me know if need more info.

Note: div with class copy is their but i haven't pasted it here.

```
<div class="modal-body aaa" id="myList">
     <div class="input-group after_add_more control-group">
          <span class="form-control" id="reportrange">
              <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>&nbsp;
              <span></span> <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
          </span>
          <div class="input-group-append">
             <button class="btn btn-success" onClick="cloneElement('copy', this)" type="button"><i
             class="fa fa-plus-square"></i></button>
         </div>
     </div>
</div>


<script>
var start = moment().subtract(29, 'days');
var end = moment();
var options = {
    startDate: start,
    endDate: end,
    ranges: {
        'Today': [moment(), moment()],
        'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
        'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
        'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
        'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
        'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf(
            'month')]
    }
}
var count = 1;
function cloneElement(clone, element) {
    count++;
    $("." + clone).find('.reportrange').attr("id", count);
    var html = $("." + clone).html();
    $('#myList').append(html);
    $('#' + count).daterangepicker(options, cb);
    cb(start, end);
    function cb(start, end) {
        $('#' + count + ' span').html(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));
    }
}
</script>
```

**UPDATED:**

```
<!-- Copy Fields -->
<div class="copy d-none">
<div class="input-group control-group mt-4">
    <span class="form-control reportrange" id="reportrange">
        <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>&nbsp;
        <span></span> <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </span>
    <div class="input-group-append">
        <button class="btn btn-danger" onClick="removeElement(this)" type="button"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: First off, look at the beginning of the cloneElement function.  When the button gets clicked, it fires off $("." + clone).find('.reportrange').attr("id", count); with the variable clone filled with the word "copy", so your selector is looking for an element with a class of "copy", but from the HTML you supplied, it doesn't exist.  Try stepping through your function and start fixing from that statement onward.

Comment: Ohh sorry i forgot to mentioned the div with class clone is their i just not added it here my mistake

Comment: OK.  If you could please add it that would be great so I can get a better idea of what's going on.  Thanks.

Comment: Okay I will add it

Comment: Hey please check I have added it

Comment: It works when I used http://www.daterangepicker.com/#examples basic daterangerpicker and doesn't work using moment.

Comment: OK, I mocked it up here https://jsbin.com/deqijezigo/edit?html,js,console,output to mess around with it and the problem I was running into was that the count variable was getting reset to 1 after the append was called, so I moved the append down further and it's now outputting the date picker.  Check out the JS, try it on your end, and see if that works for you.  If it doesn't work for you, then it might be a weird issue with jsbin and I'll mock your problem up elsewhere.